# HTML, javascript form check with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am having an issue with the following code:
If you run the following code you get a form with 3 fields: Student ID, Course ID and e-mail. Using javascript i have to check if the student field has 7 characters with two first beeing CS followed by 5 digits. I have to do the same check with the Course ID field but for 5 characters starting with CL followed by 3 digits. The Student ID check works fine but the Course ID does not. From what i see i dont have a mistake ? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function validateForm() {

         var name = document.forms["mainForm"]["id"].value;
         if(name.length != 7) {
             alert("Student ID field must be 7 characters");
             return false;
         }
         var csRegex = name.match(/\bCS/);

         if(csRegex != "CS") {
             alert("Student ID must start with CS prefix");
             return false;
         } 

         var digitsRegex = name.match(/[0-9]/g);

         if(digitsRegex.length != 5) {
             alert("Student ID must start with CS prefix followed by 5 digits");
             return false;
         }

         var courseVar = document.forms["mainForm"]["course"].value;

         if(courseVar.length != 5) {
             alert("Course ID must be 5 characters");
             return false;
         }

         var clRegex = courseVar.match(/\bCL/);
         if(clRegex != "CL") {
             alert("Course id must start with CL prefix");
             return false;
         }

         var digitsCourseRegex = courseVar.match(/[0-9]/b);
         if(digitsCourseRegex.length != 5) {
             alert("Course ID must have 3 digits after CL"); 
             return false;
         }


    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="mainForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
Student ID:<br>
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="7" required>
<br>
Course ID:<br>
<input type="text" name="course" maxlength="5" required>
<br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="email" name="mail" required>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s9n8fekg/**

Comment: Wow thanks man, one more question, my exercise needs the checks to be done with js. Can you tell me why the above code works only for Student ID form ?

Comment: This is the key regex you want: ^CS\d{5}$ (both the string and number validation).

Comment: @KostasRim, check out the HTML5 pattern attribute for input: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input - I think the OP wants a JS solution tho...

Comment: @pherris Thanks for the good info, i did know what pattern is but the exercise is to apply the check in js code. Give me a sec i want to check the regex you gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS solution is to use a better regular expression to validate the entire string at once:

```
"CS23444".match(/CS\d{5}/)
```

adeneo's answer is correct and may be the better actual solution - except it doesn't use JS, it uses HTML5. If he posts an answer that you are OK with, I'd accept that one!

Comment: I cant thank you enough, it was really simple, there was no need for spaggeti code :/

Answer (score -1):

Should `var digitsCourseRegex = courseVar.match(/[0-9]/b);` be var `digitsCourseRegex = courseVar.match(/[0-9]/g);`, With the difference being the `/b);` or the `/g);`?

Comment: /b postfix indicates before end or the last digits. /g is global match.

Comment: A bit of both. @KostasRim thanks, I didn't know what that meant. I thought maybe had made a typo.